# Reach to the required ticks of the simulation

Tags: netlogo

Dear Netlogo community,

I have created a simulation enviornment on Netlogo, which runs around 35000 ticks. It takes around 70 to 80 mins to execute completely. I am facing some errors at the end of simulation (near 25000 ticks). Now I am debugging program by using print command. simulation takes 45 to 50 mins to reach to the desired tick (a ticks that creates problem). Is there any fast way in Netlogo by using which i can reach to the desired tick quickly.

Comment: You could export everything a little bit before the problem occurs and then import everything to start from that point. I am not sure if this helps you though as I am not really sure whether the problem always occurs at the same time (if you have a fixed random seed for example) and it may be hard to modify and test code if you import something that doesn't make sense after the code changes

Comment: If the error never occurs before tick 20000, for example, you could keep the print statement from executing before then using, for example, `if ticks > 20000 [print ...]`.  That way, you won't have the delay caused by all of the print statements, at least.  Also, I assume you're unchecking the "view updates" box to make the model go as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

As JenB suggests, use the `export-world` and `import-world` primitives to save and restore world state. Or use the equivalent menu items of the same names on NetLogo's File menu.